# Is there a way to multiply Prometheus metrics, but persist label when one of the metrics misses a label?

Tags: prometheus, promql

Let's say I have 2 following metrics:

```
metric1{identifier="test", name="first"} 100
metric1{identifier="test", name="second"} 200

metric2{identifier="test", othername="third"} 2
```

I want to write a PromQL that will multiply the first metric with the second one on a specific label (`identifier` here), while persisting all the other labels in the resulting metric (`name` and `othername` here), so the result would be:

```
resultmetric{identifier="test", name="first", othername="third"} 200
resultmetric{identifier="test", name="second", othername="third"} 400
```

Simply multiplying it won't work, as these metrics have different set of labels.

How can I make this possible, if there's a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
metric1 * on(identifier) group_left(othername) metric2
```

It will multiply every `metric1` metric by the `metric2` metric with the same `identifier` label, while adding `othername` label from `metric2` to the result.

See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) for more details.